# Matlab - increase resolution of pattern in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, resolution

I have stored pattern in array, which is 1xM size.

```
Pattern = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

When plotted, it is square 3x3 where 1s are highlited.

I would like to increase resolution 4 times. So my square is now 12x12.

I tried `imresize` but I failed. I was also thinking to create 12x12 matrix with zeros and somehow fill it based on my original array.

The best way is to show a picture. One the left side is what i have and on the right side is what i'd like to have.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`repelem`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) (introduced in R2015a):

```
Pattern = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0];
Pattern = reshape(Pattern, 3, 3);
N = 4;
Result = repelem(Pattern, N, N);
```

Or simply use indexing as follows:

```
Pattern = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0];
Pattern = reshape(Pattern, 3, 3);
N = 4;
Result = Pattern(1/N:1/N:size(Pattern,1), 1/N:1/N:size(Pattern,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `imresize` failed you.  It works fine but you need to **make sure you use nearest neighbour interpolation**.  The default interpolation method for `imresize` is bicubic which is probably why you weren't getting the right answer.  Specify an additional third parameter that is a string overriding the interpolation scheme and in your case, you'll want to use nearest neighbour - i.e. `'nearest'`:

```
Pattern = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]; 
P = reshape(Pattern, 3, 3);
N = 4;
out = imresize(P, N, 'nearest');
```

We get:

```
>> out

out =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: I did not use the other parameter with `imresize`. I already used solution from @LuisMendo answer. But I will keep this for next time. Thank you!

Comment: @HonzaB no problem :) I just wanted to point out that you need to use nearest neighbour interpolation. All the best!